# How do I change the cursor highlight settings in a PowerShell session (psreadline config?)

Tags: windows, powershell

I specifically want to change which text is highlighted when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + (ARROW_FORWARD | ARROW_BACKWARD).

Here are some examples of the current behavior.

So here I would prefer the cursor stop at the end of the first word, not before the beginning of the next one:

[image]

And here I would prefer it stop right after the "a", but it seems PowerShell disregards special characters.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started, though it doesn't match your intended criteria exactly. Not sure what to do with the trailing space being selected.

Check out `Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler | Where-Object Key -eq "Ctrl+Shift+RightArrow"`. This will show you the function called by this key combination, which is `SelectNextWord`. This function operates similarly to `NextWord`, relying on the `WordDelimiters` set by `Set-PSReadLineOption`.

Clearing the delimiters will give you the same results in your first example and will select only "$a " (trailing space) in your second example. Set this with `Set-PSReadlineOption -WordDelimiters ""`.

To revert to the original delimiters, restart your PowerShell session or restore to the defaults that are mentioned in `Get-Help` for the cmdlet (`;:,.[]{}()/\|^&*-=+---`).